# Limit docker (or docker-compose) resources GLOBALLY

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04, docker-container

i'm kinda new to docker and docker compose, plus i recently switched back to ubuntu from a year or so of using osx.

I am working with some docker-compose projects that are quite resource consuming, and when configuring the env on ubuntu i stumbled across a problem: when using docker on a mac (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/) you can specify maximum resources allocation -like hd space, memory, cpu - for the entire system (so to speak) in the docker app - in ubuntu i didn't find such thing anywhere.

I saw that there is a way to do this for some specific container, but what if i want to - say - allow a max of 6GB of ram for ALL containers? Is there a way to do this i'm not seeing?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to setup a cgroup with limited CPU and Memory and refer Docker engine to it

example for a cgroup configs in "/etc/systemd/system/my_docker_slice.slice":

```
[Unit]
Description=my cgroup for Docker
Before=slices.target

[Slice]
MemoryAccounting=true
MemoryHigh=2G
MemoryMax=2.5G
CPUAccounting=true
CPUQuota=50%
```

and then update your docker `daemon.json` in `/etc/docker/`

```
{
  "cgroup-parent": "/my_docker_slice.slice"
}
```

Note:

> If the cgroup has a leading forward slash (/), the cgroup is created
> under the root cgroup, otherwise the cgroup is created under the
> daemon cgroup.

you can read more by search after "Default cgroup parent" [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)